# Can I make a "Repeat" statement with functions?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to make a function that allows you to repeat a given action a set number of times. But no matter what number I put in the "repeat" argument, it only executes "action" once.
Here's the code:

```
def repeat(repeat,action):
  for num in range(repeat):
    action


repeat(3,print("text"))
```

Here's a varient of the code that still failed:

```
def doUntil(condition, action):
  while condition != True:
    action
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to use the function like this, you first need to have something that *can be passed to the function and used later*. When you write `repeat(3,print("text"))`, this means: **call `print("text")` now** (which will display the text), and call `repeat` using **the return value from `print`** (which will be `None`). Please see the linked duplicates for a full explanation.

Comment: Parameters are evaluated before calling the repeat function so your action only contains the result not the function call.  For a single function, you could define your repeat function to accept a function and its parameters and make the actual calls inside your own loop: `def repeat(times,func,*args,**kwargs): for _ in range(times):func(*args,**kwargs)`.  You would then call it with the repeat count, the function name and the parameters to give it: 
`repeat(3,print,"hello world")`

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your first code snippet is that you are calling the `print()` function when passing it as an argument to the `repeat()` function. This means that the `print()` **function will be executed before the** `repeat()` function is even called, and the return value of `print()` (which is `None`) will be passed as the action argument to `repeat()`. So essentially, you are just passing `None` to `repeat()` as the action argument, and then trying to execute it repeatedly. So you need to do it this way to create a new function and pass it as an argument like this.

```
def repeat(repeat, action):
  for num in range(repeat):
    action()

def print_text():
  print("text")

repeat(3, print_text)
```

**Output:**

```
text
text
text
```